# Is there an inconsistency about Natasha Romanoff's middle name in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, captain-america-the-winter-soldier, black-widow

In *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, when Natasha and Captain America meet what's left of Arnim Zola in the bunker at Camp Lehigh, he addresses Natasha as:

> **Dr. Arnim Zola**: *Rogers, Steven. Born, 1918. **Romanoff, Natalia Alianovna**. Born, 1984.* [they see an old camera moving above them as it analyzes them]
>
> **Natasha Romanoff**: *It's some kind of a recording.*
>
> **Dr. Arnim Zola**: *I am not a recording, Fräulein* [...]
>
> <sub>*Captain America: The Winter Soldier*</sub>

And in *Avengers: Endgame*, when Clint and Natasha arrive at Vormir, we see Red Skull address Black Widow as:

> Red Skull: *Welcome.*
>
> [*Natasha and Clint draws their weapons*]
>
> Red Skull: ***Natasha, daughter of Ivan***. Clint, son of Edith.
>
> Natasha: *Who are you?* [...]
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

As far as I know, **Ivan** couldn't have been a nickname for **Alianovna** (*e.g., Bob for Robert or Bill for William etc.*). And as I found [here](https://www.names.org/n/alianovna/about), Alianovna is not specified to be a female or a male name.

So, is this an inconsistency on the part of the writers of the movies? Or is there any official/unofficial source that tells us why the her middle name was differently mentioned in the two films?

**PS**: Zola's mind was transferred into a complex computer system and he possessed knowledge that no one knew (as seen in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*). Also, Cosmic Red Skull seemed to possess the information about everyone who visited Vormir (in *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Avengers: Endgame* as well). So, I assume that both of them knew what they were talking about.

Comment: Alianovna means "daughter of Alian".

Comment: Her surname already shows that her name doesn't follow a general naming scheme, otherwise her last name would be Romanova or Romanovna; '-off' or 'ov' are typically male versions of surnames.

Comment: @TylerH That's something that's always bugged me.  For instance, Vladimir Putin's ex-wife and daughters' surname was Putina (the younger still is) .  So Natasha/Natalia's father may well have been a Romanov, but she would be a Romanovna.

Comment: This question confused me because I was not aware of this link between middle names and names of parents (and it also isn't explained in the question). But I suppose if you knew not everyone knows this, you wouldn't have had this question.

Comment: Do you assume that Clint's middle name is "son of Edith"?

Comment: @MontyHarder the last name could only be Romanova. Romanovna is a patronymic ("daughter of Roman"); Romanova - a last name ("female descendant of Roman").

Comment: @TylerH, the gendered surname is often dropped when moving west. It's too much hassle in Western bureaucracies to have a surname that doesn't match the parent's.

Comment: It's the Soul Stone, So I think it's more the soul father. We need Peter Parker visiting Red skull a multiple moment of his life, to make further hypothesis.

Comment: @KyleStrand not sure why you assume that's the assumption. Middle names in the US do not necessarily refer to the father's name. Some do, but it's a lot less strict than a Russian name where the middle name almost exclusively comes from the father. If Black Widow's name was "Natasha Ivanovna Romanoff" then the "daughter of Ivan". The "son of Edith" does not need to match any of Hawkeye's real names. So I don't think anybody assumes his full name is "Clint Edith Barton".

Comment: To be honest, it would be more surprising if her middle name _did_ align with her father's name. Because then it would have been no impressive feat at all for Red Skull to know who her father was. He'd just have to know her middle name - super easy, barely an inconvenience. I wonder if she had a specific reason to redact her father's name from her own (perhaps to deliberately hide his identity, making RS's feat even more impressive). Maybe the upcoming movie will answer this.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no inconsistency with her middle name if her name isn't following the general Russian naming convention. Her full name is, as we find out from Arnim Zola, Natalia Alianovna Romanoff, and Red Skull is simply saying that her father's name is Ivan, not that that is her middle name.

People do have different middle names from their parents' first names, in some cultures this would even be the norm. For an example in the MCU we have Iron Man whose full name is Anthony Edward Stark and his father's full name is Howard Anthony Walter Stark. Here, Tony's first name actually comes from his father's middle name, not his middle name coming from his father's first name.

---

After a bit more research, though, it would seem that Russia generally uses the naming convention of:

```
<first name> <patronymic> <last name>
```

As such this would mean from Nat's patronymic her father's name should be Alian. Or her middle name should have been Ivanovna/Ivanevna. However, in the comics (Earth-616) it is revealed that Ivan Petrovich Bezukhov is actually Nat's adoptive father after saving her from rubble as we see in *Black Widow: Deadly Origin* Issue 1.

[image: Comic page showing what the above paragraph describes]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Therefore, it would seem that Nat's actual father in the MCU should be called Alian and Ivan is actually her adoptive father's name if they are true to the comics. Perhaps we'll find out more in *Black Widow*.

To further this Ivan Antonovich Vanko, aka Whiplash, who we see in *Iron Man 2* has the father Anton Vanko. Here the middle name is a patronymic for his father and he is Russian. It would seem then like Nat's father in the MCU is actually called Alian, but Ivan adopted and raised her. Maybe Red Skull is going by the same motivations in his statement as Yondu does to Peter.

> **Yondu Udonta:** He may have been your father, boy, but he wasn’t your daddy.
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*</sub>

Either that or the MCU has forgone Russian naming conventions just for a small Easter Egg to the comics which isn't entirely impossible.

---

It's also worth noting that in *Avengers: Endgame* Nat says she never knew her father's name. This can still make sense in that she knew her middle name because she says *"I didn't"* which can mean she didn't until Arnim told her, her middle name or she didn't until Red Skull just told her.

> **Clint Barton:** Why, 'cause he knows your Daddy's name?
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** I didn't. Thanos left here with the stone without his daughter. It's not a coincidence.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

She may also have known her actual father's name, from Arnim, but not her adoptive one. Red Skull does seem to use a person's *"daddy"* rather than their proper father as we see when Thanos and Gamora go to him.

> **Red Skull:** Welcome, Thanos, son of A'lars. Gamora, daughter of Thanos.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Comment: I suppose its the cultural difference then. Because, in India, the middle name is actually the father's name: <name> <father's name> <family_name/surname>.

Comment: @Shreedhar I've done a bit more research and updated, there may actually be a small inconsistency here.

Comment: This is quite a find . **Alian + Ivanovna = Alianovna** ? :p Oh how the mind of the writers work :p

Comment: Note that Nat does say in Endgame that she never knew her father's name. As such, her middle name wouldn't have been likely to come from her “actual” father (for whatever value of “actual” the Red Skull/Soul Stone uses, given that Gamora is described as daughter of Thay-nos).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It's possible she never knew her middle name until Arnim says it in TWS. I think the scene in Endgame would still make sense with that interpretation. I'll edit this in, in a minute though because it's a good point.

Comment: @Shreedhar not really. -ovna means "daughter of"

Comment: Interesting that he chose Clint's mother and not his father (at least I assume since I've never heard of "Edith" as a man's name), which I assume meant he always went with the opposite-gendered parent, but then "A'lars" is evidently male according to a quick Google search, so I don't know.  I'm not sure if Thanos' species even has binary gender since we've only ever seen one representative of them.

Comment: There is a theory (albeit a stretchy one) that Thanos is Gamora's biological father.

Comment: Who else thinks that comic books are nerd soap operas?

Comment: @RonJohn - In roughly the same way that Pro Wrestling is jock soap operas, yes.

Answer (score 5):

There is only one option regarding middle name in Russian (and in all Slavonian countries) - in fact it is patronymic but not a second name.
And it always equals to the [name of the FATHER] + [possessive ending] like "son of" "daughter of".

Regarding "Alianovna" - it sounds like a joke or might be a bad transcription. There is no such Slavonian name (at least for now).

That means if Natasha's father is Ivan - she definitely has 'legal' second name - [Ivan]ovna.

Comment: ...which is quite possibly **what was in fact said**, and whoever transcribed it into the form written in the question mistakenly wrote "Alianova" instead of "Ivanovna". To someone who doesn't hear Russian names every day, the one may well have sounded like the other.

Comment: @T.E.D. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AUs3J995Fc.  Transcript sounds accurate to me.

Comment: Do you mean [Slavic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavs)? [Slavonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavonia) seems something else altogether.